# Web2py Creating a Rest Client

Tags: python, web2py

I am a newbie to Web2py and Python and I am trying to add requests
(http://docs.python-requests.org) however I am unsure how to add
this to my current Web2py environment. 
I am running OSX with Web2Py 2.12.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the Mac binary version of web2py, it includes its own Python interpreter (so if you have Python installed on your system, it will ignore any libraries available in your system Python installation). To make requests available to your web2py app, you can either put the `requests` package in the app's `/modules` folder, or you can put it in the web2py `/site-packages` folder, which on the Mac is inside `/Contents/Resources`.

However, a better option is probably just to install Python on your machine and then use the source version of web2py instead of the Mac binary. Then you can use `pip` to install any external libraries and they will be available when running web2py.